# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get searchkick to work but I run into an error when I attempt to **reindex** my stories via the console. I can't seem to understand what the error might be and would love some help.

The error via the console after entering "Story.reindex":

```
Story Import (3.6ms)  {"count":2,"exception":["ArgumentError","wrong 
number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)"],"exception_object":"wrong 
number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)"}
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
    from app/models/story.rb:42:in `hot_score'
    from (irb):1
```

**story.rb model:**

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord
searchkick

has_many :votes

scope :newest, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
scope :hottest, -> { order(hot_score: :desc) }

def upvotes
 votes.sum(:upvote)
end

def downvotes
 votes.sum(:downvote)
end

def calc_hot_score
 points = upvotes - downvotes
 time_ago_in_hours = ((Time.now - created_at) / 3600).round
 score = hot_score(points, time_ago_in_hours)

 update_attributes(points: points, hot_score: score)
end

private

def hot_score(points, time_ago_in_hours, gravity = 1.8)
 (points - 1) / (time_ago_in_hours + 2) ** gravity
end
end
```

Can anyone help explain what is going on and maybe a way to get around it? I'm still pretty new to Ruby.

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: How are you calling hot_score()? This method takes two arguments: `points` and `time_ago_in_hours`. The error suggests you are not passing in these two arguments.

Comment: Where would I find this calling hot_score()? Which files so I can give you an answer?

Comment: What is the output of Story.first.calc_hot_score ?

Comment: It gives the following error `NoMethodError: undefined method `first_calc_hot_score' for Story (call 'Story.connection' to establish a connection):Class`

Comment: @miklki14567, I am assuming your in the rails console (`rails c`). This `NoMethodError` problem can be fixed by first calling `Story.connection`. Also, you said "when I attempt to reindex my stories via the console" you are getting your original error. How exactly are you doing this? What specific commands are you running in console?

Comment: @possiblyLethal I'm in the rails console. So should I call `Story.connection` and then call `Story.first.calc_hot_score` again?

Comment: I did this and it gives me the following error: **Story Store (0.8ms)  {"id":1,"exception":["ArgumentError","wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)"],"exception_object":"wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)"}
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
        from app/models/story.rb:42:in `hot_score'
        from app/models/story.rb:37:in `calc_hot_score'
        from (irb):4**

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: @architgupta Postgres

Comment: What happens if you rename your private def `hot_score` to something that isint also the name of a database column?

Comment: @possiblyLethal I can give that a try. But won't that break everything? Because  `t.float "hot_score", default: 0.0` is inside the stories database table.

Comment: Since you haven't provided a stack-trace I can't tell you exactly where this is coming from, but my advice to you is carefully read the error stack-trace, and you should be able to track down where this method is being called (without arguments) which is causing the error